# Querying a sql "event log" schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, event-log

Given this schema (in postgresql-9.2):

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   ...other columns elided...
);

CREATE TYPE event_type AS ENUM ('start', 'stop');

CREATE TABLE foo_event (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   foo_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES foo (id),
   timestamp timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   type event_type NOT NULL
);
```

How can I get all "running" `foo`s? That is, `foo`s whose most recent event is a 'start', or, even better, `foo`s who were started at least once, and have no `stop`s after their last `start` (in case I add more event types in the future).

---

My best attempt so far is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM foo
 WHERE id NOT IN
 (SELECT foo_id FROM foo_event
  WHERE type='stop');
```

The problem here is, of course, that it'll never return any `foo`s that have ever been stopped.

Comment: Why to use NOT in.  Instead use IN without where clause  in sub query. That will give both types of record s

Comment: Can there be multiple `start` events without corresponding `stop` events? If not, something along these lines: `GROUP BY foo_id HAVING SUM(CASE event_type = 'start' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > SUM(CASE event_type = 'stop' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `MAX()` aggregate to retrieve the most recent `start` event per `foo_id` group, you can do a `LEFT JOIN` against a subquery which retrieves the most recent (also `MAX()`) `stop` event which is greater than the `start` event in the `ON` clause.  Look for those with `NULL`s in the `stop` events subquery, meaning no match.

```
SELECT 
  foo.*,
  fstart.*
FROM 
  foo 
  INNER JOIN (
   /* Left side gets most recent start events */
   SELECT
    foo_id, 
    MAX(timestamp) AS start_ts
   FROM
    foo_event
   WHERE event_type = 'start'
   GROUP BY foo_id
 ) fstart ON foo.id = fstart.foo_id
 /* Right side gets most recent stop events */
 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    foo_id,
    MAX(timestamp) AS stop_ts
  FROM
    foo_event
  WHERE event_type = 'stop'
  GROUP BY foo_id
 /* JOIN rows that have a greater stop time than start time */
 ) fstop ON fstart.foo_id = fstop.foo_id AND fstop.stop_ts > fstart.start_ts
 /* And find rows where there's no matching stop event greater than the start */
WHERE fstop.stop_ts IS NULL
```

#### And look at that, it actually works! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8642d/1

Note, use `>=` rather than `>` in the `ON` clause, if a stop event can end at the same time as its corresponding start event...

Comment: Hey this is awesome! Looking at the query plan I see it's doing table scans (of course). What indexes should I add to avoid that? `foo_event.timestamp`, `foo_event.type`, any others?

Comment: @Dan Index `foo_id` definitely, maybe a compound index across `(foo_id, timestamp)`?

Comment: I think only the `foo_event.type` index gets used according to my parsing of http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4e752/1/0 -- anyway, thanks a bunch!